# Black lines in my label texture showing up

Tags: bezier-curves

I added this label using a Bézier curve and in cycles it keeps showing these black lines in the render, what can I go to get rid of these?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i noticed that when i see black in cycles rendering, it usually is overlapping geometry.  can you attach your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: thanks for the reply! it has something to do with the edge loops on the label being stretched too far I think, but I don't know a way around it
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9aPbr1no" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9aPbr1no/)

Comment: maybe it's the overlapping vertices. go into edit mode and press `a` then `m` *merge by distance*, it will remove 2 duplicate vertices. try that

Comment: and also the cap, it merges 700+ duplicate vertices and also the body has 50,000 vertices overlapping. you have a ton of overlapping duplicate vertices for each object and some really bad and dense topology which was unwrapped badly as well. consider modeling it again, at least the cap needs remodeling.